# Navigation links do not load correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open a page `studio-x.net.au` then after waiting for 5 seconds js setTimeout opens about section of page incorrectly as https://www.studio-x.net.au/#about and in wrong position.

I have tried:

```js
setTimeout("window.location.href=\"#about\";", 5000);
```

and this

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    window.top.location.href="/#about"
} , 5000);
```

and currently Eric's suggestion

```js
setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.replace('#about');}, 5000);
```

all seem to work to open but does not display as desired.

Are my navigation links the problem? ie. href="#about"

The behavior that I have issue with is when js triggers page opens on https://www.studio-x.net.au/#about in incorrect position.

When you use click on mouse or click on nav, about page opens as intended on the about page and shows only https://www.studio-x.net.au in url,

likewise on other sections such as portfolio, pricing, contact sections showing only https://www.studio-x.net.au in url.

Once triggered the https://www.studio-x.net.au/#about in incorrect position continues possibly cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  window.location.replace('#about');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion Eric, I have used and get same issue, which makes me think it is not the js function that is my problem. Instead the nav links behavior.